# Help identify the tool generating certificate displays on the EU eIDAS Dashboard

Tags: certificates, openssl

The EU eIDAS Dashboard serves as a repository for trusted "trust providers" in accordance with the eIDAS regulation. The provider's certificates are listed within the dashboard.

You can find [an example](https://eidas.ec.europa.eu/efda/tl-browser/#/screen/tl/BE/11/3) here.

To retrieve the certificate in DER format, it can be obtained as a base64-encoded string by clicking the "Base 64-encoded" button located at the bottom of the page. (Alternatively refer to the copied information below.)

I am curious what tool produced the outputs available using the buttons "Certificate Information" and "ASN1". Both are copied below as well for posterity.

I found that `openssl x509 -inform DER -in test.crt -noout -text` has a slightly different output format.  For instance, the "SerialNumber" field is encoded as a hexadecimal value by openssl, whereas in the "Certificate Information," it is presented as a base10 integer.

Does anybody recognise the specific output formatting of the outputs titled "Certificate Information" and "ASN1" by chance?

---

**Base 64-encoded**

```
MIIERzCCA86gAwIBAgIUEFsEYuhn+NxO8EbEovbXNQS+YskwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwMwgbsxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkJFMREwDwYDVQQHDAhCcnVzc2VsczEwMC4GA1UECgwnS2luZ2RvbSBvZiBCZWxnaXVtIC0gRmVkZXJhbCBHb3Zlcm5tZW50MT8wPQYDVQQLDDZRVFNQOiBGUFMgUG9saWN5IGFuZCBTdXBwb3J0IC0gQk9TQSAoTlRSQkUtMDY3MTUxNjY0NykxDzANBgNVBAUTBjIwMjEwMTEVMBMGA1UEAwwMVGltZXN0YW1wIENBMB4XDTIxMDMxNjA5NDAyNFoXDTI3MDMxNjA5NDAyNFowgb0xCzAJBgNVBAYTAkJFMREwDwYDVQQHDAhCcnVzc2VsczEwMC4GA1UECgwnS2luZ2RvbSBvZiBCZWxnaXVtIC0gRmVkZXJhbCBHb3Zlcm5tZW50MT8wPQYDVQQLDDZRVFNQOiBGUFMgUG9saWN5IGFuZCBTdXBwb3J0IC0gQk9TQSAoTlRSQkUtMDY3MTUxNjY0NykxDzANBgNVBAUTBjIwMjEwMjEXMBUGA1UEAwwOVGltZXN0YW1wIFVuaXQwWTATBgcqhkjOPQIBBggqhkjOPQMBBwNCAAQgW045n8P+kf/32AZ+HfDC+it91DWvUg1VuyLBPXklBXS2aJ3SoWleLm9dbBIR+dN2VnGNpxJeWJwkrLV6ed6Co4IBqjCCAaYwDAYDVR0TAQH/BAIwADAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBTgThvTdU21h04CtvqpWmPMPKqYmTB7BggrBgEFBQcBAQRvMG0wOgYIKwYBBQUHMAKGLmh0dHA6Ly9jcnQuZWlkcGtpLmJlbGdpdW0uYmUvdHMvdHNjYTIwMjEwMS5jcnQwLwYIKwYBBQUHMAGGI2h0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLmVpZHBraS5iZWxnaXVtLmJlL2VpZC8wMFYGA1UdIARPME0wQAYHYDgNBgOHaDA1MDMGCCsGAQUFBwIBFidodHRwczovL3JlcG9zaXRvcnkuZWlkcGtpLmJlbGdpdW0uYmUvdHMwCQYHBACL7EABATAWBgNVHSUBAf8EDDAKBggrBgEFBQcDCDAYBggrBgEFBQcBAwQMMAowCAYGBACORgEBMD8GA1UdHwQ4MDYwNKAyoDCGLmh0dHA6Ly9jcmwuZWlkcGtpLmJlbGdpdW0uYmUvdHMvdHNjYTIwMjEwMS5jcmwwHQYDVR0OBBYEFCz5Qqc7x2eYCEXyMH4p6AYCG5EQMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIHgDAKBggqhkjOPQQDAwNnADBkAjB0oreRkNZ7AxdtICH6lkW8nERAwDPWP8w5BUSZL8sJ5KrootY9gevtIn1+FbFTJRACMAi8hy0yn0pO0Pl4wzCmgcRhpaPmsmeJ8j3bo573kh1MK4psbY2Q3swkNu+8QWmi3g==
```

**Certificate Information**

```
  [0]         Version: 3
         SerialNumber: 93373602251984153477303393981460392060238324425
             IssuerDN: C=BE,L=Brussels,O=Kingdom of Belgium - Federal Government,OU=QTSP: FPS Policy and Support - BOSA (NTRBE-0671516647),SERIALNUMBER=202101,CN=Timestamp CA
           Start Date: Tue Mar 16 10:40:24 CET 2021
           Final Date: Tue Mar 16 10:40:24 CET 2027
            SubjectDN: C=BE,L=Brussels,O=Kingdom of Belgium - Federal Government,OU=QTSP: FPS Policy and Support - BOSA (NTRBE-0671516647),SERIALNUMBER=202102,CN=Timestamp Unit
           Public Key: EC Public Key [5f:9f:f9:05:a8:56:27:c6:cb:30:c8:f3:34:55:f1:92:98:4d:ad:d7]
            X: 205b4e399fc3fe91fff7d8067e1df0c2fa2b7dd435af520d55bb22c13d792505
            Y: 74b6689dd2a1695e2e6f5d6c1211f9d37656718da7125e589c24acb57a79de82

  Signature Algorithm: SHA384WITHECDSA
            Signature: 3064023074a2b79190d67b03176d2021fa9645bc
                       9c4440c033d63fcc390544992fcb09e4aae8a2d6
                       3d81ebed227d7e15b1532510023008bc872d329f
                       4a4ed0f978c330a681c461a5a3e6b26789f23ddb
                       a39ef7921d4c2b8a6c6d8d90decc2436efbc4169
                       a2de
       Extensions: 
                       critical(true) BasicConstraints: isCa(false)
                       critical(false) 2.5.29.35 value = Sequence
    Tagged [CONTEXT 0] IMPLICIT 
        DER Octet String[20] 

                       critical(false) 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 value = Sequence
    Sequence
        ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2)
        Tagged [CONTEXT 6] IMPLICIT 
            DER Octet String[46] 
    Sequence
        ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1)
        Tagged [CONTEXT 6] IMPLICIT 
            DER Octet String[35] 

                       critical(false) 2.5.29.32 value = Sequence
    Sequence
        ObjectIdentifier(2.16.56.13.6.3.1000)
        Sequence
            Sequence
                ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1)
                IA5String(https://repository.eidpki.belgium.be/ts) 
    Sequence
        ObjectIdentifier(0.4.0.194112.1.1)

                       critical(true) 2.5.29.37 value = Sequence
    ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.8)

                       critical(false) 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.3 value = Sequence
    Sequence
        ObjectIdentifier(0.4.0.1862.1.1)

                       critical(false) 2.5.29.31 value = Sequence
    Sequence
        Tagged [CONTEXT 0]
            Tagged [CONTEXT 0]
                Tagged [CONTEXT 6] IMPLICIT 
                    DER Octet String[46] 

                       critical(false) 2.5.29.14 value = DER Octet String[20] 

                       critical(true) KeyUsage: 0x80
```

**ASN1**

```
SEQUENCE {
   SEQUENCE {
      [0] {
         INTEGER 0x02 (2 decimal)
      }
      INTEGER 0x105b0462e867f8dc4ef046c4a2f6d73504be62c9
      SEQUENCE {
         OBJECTIDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.4.3.3 (ecdsa-with-SHA384)
      }
      SEQUENCE {
         SET {
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.4.6 (countryName)
               PrintableString 'BE'
            }
         }
         SET {
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.4.7 (localityName)
               UTF8String 'Brussels'
            }
         }
         SET {
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.4.10 (organizationName)
               UTF8String 'Kingdom of Belgium - Federal Government'
            }
         }
         SET {
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.4.11 (organizationalUnitName)
               UTF8String 'QTSP: FPS Policy and Support - BOSA (NTRBE-0671516647)'
            }
         }
         SET {
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.4.5 (serialNumber)
               PrintableString '202101'
            }
         }
         SET {
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.4.3 (commonName)
               UTF8String 'Timestamp CA'
            }
         }
      }
      SEQUENCE {
         UTCTime '210316094024Z'
         UTCTime '270316094024Z'
      }
      SEQUENCE {
         SET {
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.4.6 (countryName)
               PrintableString 'BE'
            }
         }
         SET {
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.4.7 (localityName)
               UTF8String 'Brussels'
            }
         }
         SET {
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.4.10 (organizationName)
               UTF8String 'Kingdom of Belgium - Federal Government'
            }
         }
         SET {
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.4.11 (organizationalUnitName)
               UTF8String 'QTSP: FPS Policy and Support - BOSA (NTRBE-0671516647)'
            }
         }
         SET {
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.4.5 (serialNumber)
               PrintableString '202102'
            }
         }
         SET {
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.4.3 (commonName)
               UTF8String 'Timestamp Unit'
            }
         }
      }
      SEQUENCE {
         SEQUENCE {
            OBJECTIDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.2.1 (ecPublicKey)
            OBJECTIDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7 (P-256)
         }
         BITSTRING 0x04205b4e399fc3fe91fff7d8067e1df0c2fa2b7dd435af520d55bb22c13d79250574b6689dd2a1695e2e6f5d6c1211f9d37656718da7125e589c24acb57a79de82 : 0 unused bit(s)
      }
      [3] {
         SEQUENCE {
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.29.19 (basicConstraints)
               BOOLEAN TRUE
               OCTETSTRING 3000
            }
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.29.35 (authorityKeyIdentifier)
               OCTETSTRING 30168014e04e1bd3754db5874e02b6faa95a63cc3caa9899
            }
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1
               OCTETSTRING 306d303a06082b06010505073002862e687474703a2f2f6372742e656964706b692e62656c6769756d2e62652f74732f747363613230323130312e637274302f06082b060105050730018623687474703a2f2f6f6373702e656964706b692e62656c6769756d2e62652f6569642f30
            }
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.29.32 (certificatePolicies)
               OCTETSTRING 304d3040060760380d060387683035303306082b06010505070201162768747470733a2f2f7265706f7369746f72792e656964706b692e62656c6769756d2e62652f74733009060704008bec400101
            }
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.29.37 (extKeyUsage)
               BOOLEAN TRUE
               OCTETSTRING 300a06082b06010505070308
            }
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.3
               OCTETSTRING 300a3008060604008e460101
            }
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.29.31 (cRLDistributionPoints)
               OCTETSTRING 30363034a032a030862e687474703a2f2f63726c2e656964706b692e62656c6769756d2e62652f74732f747363613230323130312e63726c
            }
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.29.14 (subjectKeyIdentifier)
               OCTETSTRING 04142cf942a73bc767980845f2307e29e806021b9110
            }
            SEQUENCE {
               OBJECTIDENTIFIER 2.5.29.15 (keyUsage)
               BOOLEAN TRUE
               OCTETSTRING 03020780
            }
         }
      }
   }
   SEQUENCE {
      OBJECTIDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.4.3.3 (ecdsa-with-SHA384)
   }
   BITSTRING 0x3064023074a2b79190d67b03176d2021fa9645bc9c4440c033d63fcc390544992fcb09e4aae8a2d63d81ebed227d7e15b1532510023008bc872d329f4a4ed0f978c330a681c461a5a3e6b26789f23ddba39ef7921d4c2b8a6c6d8d90decc2436efbc4169a2de : 0 unused bit(s)
}
```